# '#' element in url not redirecting

Tags: html, url, url-rewriting, anchor

I do not know how to use that symbol in a URL. I have this search entry, an anchor point to

'/language/pod#index-entry-declarator_blocks_%23|'.

And another anchor with the same url. But when I click on it sends me to the top of the page instead of where that anchors is. Any idea how to solve it?

Note: the last '%23' is the '#' symbol encoded.

Aclaration: I'm fixing a problem in the documentation of Perl6, where '#|' and '#=' are valid operators, by that reason they appear in the docs.

The search element is here => https://docs.perl6.org/js/search.js (ctrl f and declarators blocks)

The anchor element is here => https://docs.perl6.org/language/pod#index-entry-declarator_blocks_%23|

Comment: I have added additional information for adding a snippet is kind of tricky in this case.

Comment: It is unclear what you need here. do you want to GReP the files and change the URL or what exactly is the end result?

Comment: This works in Chrome https://docs.perl6.org/language/pod#index-entry-declarator_blocks_%23=